# Android application using phone gap

Tags: android, shell, android-layout

I successfully completed my application in android and is running in real device and simulator .My app requires internet access hence given access in manifest.xml file.

The code is like this:

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />   
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
```

Now the problem is my app is running only when the wifi is ON but not running through the internet connection in mobile. I have to run the application with out wifi in my device.

Comment: @sundheercheckuri These lines only allow your application to use this information, probably you have something else in your soruce code, java?

Comment: @pepelac Is there any other code to be built in my application, actually I had called direct url of my dotnet application in the place of super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html"); to run that application in android. can you catch what I am expressing. okay. Is there any way to access my application without wifi.

Comment: @sudheerchekuri which cordova version you are using to build app?

Comment: I am using apache 2.2.0 version. okay, no problem my issue is solved I added code lane  super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 100000); and now its running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using Apache 2.2.0 version. okay, no problem my issue is solved I added code lane `super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 100000);` and now it's running.